# I sent a bitcoin to a non coinbase email address

Tags: email

How do I retrieve a bitcoin sent to an email address from coinbase and the email address is not registered with coinbase...

Answer (score 1):

If you used the bitcoin network to send coins there is nothing you can do, once you send them you you no longer own them.
If you send bitcoin with coinbase with their service then you should contact their support service.